# How to access DB from a function and only then send a post request?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need help to integrate a few actions inside a function.

I get a call from PayPal, then i need to :

1. Access my DB to compare.
2. If ok send 200 OK
3. Send the request body back.

Currently - I do (3) **only**, and it somehow **works without** (2).

```
     exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     ....
     ....

    if(request.path === paid)
       {

               if (request.method !== "POST")
                  response.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");

               else {
                           let ipnTransactionMessage = request.body;
                           let formUrlEncodedBody = querystring.stringify(ipnTransactionMessage);
                           let verificationBody = `cmd=_notify-validate&${formUrlEncodedBody}`;

                           //______________

                          //** at this point i need to read a firebase collection and return 200OK , ONLY THEN DO THE POST BELOW


                           var docRef = admin.firestore().collection('All').doc(ipnTransactionMessage.custom);
                           docRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                             console("our data to compare",snapshot);
                             res.status(200); // ?
                           });

//**** how do i do the next only after the previous ?


                           let options = {
                                     method: 'POST',
                                     uri: "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", 
                                     body: verificationBody
                                       };
                           return rp(options)
                                  .then(body => {
                                        if (body === "VERIFIED") {
                                     //** we are done here - and this actually works already
                                })
                                .then(docReference => {
                                    console.log("Request completed");
                                    return response.send({ result: 'ok' });
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.log(error);
                                    return response.status(500).send(error);
                                });
```

See the comment in the code. **After** reading my DB and respond with `200 OK` , only then i would like to send back the body as I do.

Comment: Put the code to perform after the database query inside the `then` callback, before you send the reponse.  Sending the response terminates the entire function.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks very much, i am spending a lot of time reading about it, can you please show me in 1 line the exact semantic with the "then" ? it seems bad to just put the body respond inside the first "then"/

Comment: Should i instead return the DB access  (a promise), and chain another ".then" where i do the return rp(options) ? I am so confused.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug mentioned the code needs to go in the then clause:

I took a part of your code to shaow where the code to get executed only when firestore answers can go.

```
    //** at this point i need to read a firebase collection and return 200OK , ONLY THEN DO THE POST BELOW


             var docRef = admin.firestore().collection('All').doc(ipnTransactionMessage.custom);
             docRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
               console("our data to compare",snapshot);
               res.status(200); //
               if(snapshot.exists){
                 //  ---------------------------------
                 //  The code that you want to get executed only 
                 //  firestore answers Goes Here
                 //  ---------------------------------
                 }
               });
```